# Change Letters to numbers (ints) in python

Tags: python, switch-statement

This might be python 101, but I am having a hard time changing letters into a valid integer.

The put what I am trying to do simply

char >> [ ] >> int

I created a case statement to give me a number depending on certain characters, so  what I tried doing was

```
def char_to_int(sometext):
    return {
            'Z':1,
            'Y':17,
            'X':8,
            'w':4,
            }.get(sometext, '')
```

Which converts the letter into a number, but when I try using that number into any argument that takes ints it doesn't work.

I've tried

```
text_number = int(sometext)
```

But I get the message TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

So from there I returned the type of sometext using

```
print(type(sometext))
```

And the return type is a function.

So my question is, is there a better way to convert letters into numbers, or a better way to setup my switch/def statement

Heres the full code where its call

if sometext:
       for i in range ( 0, len(sometext)):
            char_to_int(sometext[i])

I've managed to get it working, ultimately what I changed was the default of the definition, I now set the definition to a variable before instead of calling it in another function, and I recoded the section I was using it.

Originally my definition looked liked this

```
def char_to_int(sometext):
return {
        ...
        }.get(sometext, '')
```

But I changed the default to 0, so now it looks like

```
def char_to_int(sometext):
return {
        ...
        }.get(sometext, 0)
```

The old code that called the definition looked

```
if sometext: 
          for i in range ( 0, len(sometext)): 
                    C_T_I = int(char_to_int(sometext[i]))
```

I changed it to this.

```
if sometext: 
          for i in range ( 0, len(sometext)): 
                    C_T_I = char_to_int(sometext[i])
                    TEXTNUM = int(C_T_I)
```

Hopefully this clarifies the changes. Thanks for everyone's assistance.

Comment: As the error suggests, `sometext` should be a string or a number. Why are you passing a function to the `def` ?

Comment: Please show ALL your code, not just the function.  You say "*give me a number depending on certain numbers*".  Do you mean "depending on certain letters?".

Comment: The code is roughly 300 lines longs. I just posted the part I'm having trouble with. 
In terms of "why I'm passing a function", let me run some quick test to see if it goes in as a function

Comment: As it stands, the function itself seems fine, its the way you are calling it.

Comment: @cdarke The function works in terms of returning numbers, but the type is changed to function when it returns the numbers

The char goes in as type unicode, but after running that def it goes out as type function

Comment: Your code works fine as said above, I tried running it with "i = char_to_int(u'X')"... The string I pass is unicode, all works ok, return is "<type 'int'>"... Maybe you can show as much as you can how you call the function?

Comment: How does the variable "sometext" get initialized/get its value? Because this works: http://pastebin.com/DQ5WrgKD

Comment: Its called in another function, but it does return as type unicode.

I ended up changing around the code and setting the definition to a variable instead of calling within another definition and setting the default to 0 instead of ''

Now it appears to be working. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: @ProjectPokket: not showing what you changed does not help anyone else.  Part of the advantage of this site is so other people can learn from your mistakes, but we have no idea how you fixed it.

Comment: @cdarke added the code, I changed to get me working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the python console:

`>>> type({ 'Z':1, 'Y':17, 'X':8, 'w':4, }.get('X', ''))
<class 'int'>`

so as cdarke suggested, you should look at how you are calling the function.

Comment: Changing around the code, the way it was being called and changing the default to 0 seemed to fix the issue